# Powershell capture stdout from cmd /c

Tags: powershell, stdout

I am trying to replace a batch script with a Powershell script.

The batch script calls an executable with a path parameter. The executable writes its output in stdout, and the script streams it to a file:

```
"C:\My Folder\App.exe" "C:\My Folder\appdata.dat" > "C:\My Folder\AppResult.txt"
```

I tried this Powershell code:

```
cmd /c "`"START `"abc`" `"C:\My Folder\App.exe`" `"C:\My Folder\appdata.dat`"`"" > "C:\My Folder\AppResult.txt"
```

It seems to start correctly the exe and wait for it to finish, but the file stays empty, I don't manage to capture the stdout text.

PS: If possible, it would be even better if I could get the stdout text in a variable instead of a file.

Comment: `& "C:\My Folder\App.exe" "C:\My Folder\appdata.dat" > "C:\My Folder\AppResult.txt"`

Comment: have you tried simply running the exe in powershell? many exe files will output to standard output ... and PoSh will show it in the console. what shows in the console can usually be captured to a $Var. for instance, this `$Test = quser` will store the output of the exe in the `$Test` variable.

Comment: Have you tried using `Out-Host` and `Out-File`. This is how your command should look like. `cmd /c "`"START `"abc`" `"C:\My Folder\App.exe`" `"C:\My Folder\appdata.dat`"`"" | Out-Host | Out-file  "C:\My Folder\AppResult.txt"`

Comment: `& "C:\My Folder\App.exe" "C:\My Folder\appdata.dat" > "C:\My Folder\AppResult.txt"`does not work because it does not wait for the exe to stop.

Comment: `Out-Host` and `Out-File` does not help.